# Oracle, generate Where clause based on table names

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Scenario: 
I'm passing 2 table names (f.e. Employees and departments) to pl/sql procedure.
I want to this procedure generate WHERE clause like `'WHERE employees.department_id = departments.department_id'` so basically this procedure must find key relations.

I tried to use all_constraints table to find constraint_type='P' or 'F' and then find associated column, but in this table there is no information about which column is used in constraint.
Does anybody have an idea how can I do this (mayby in diffrent way)?

Comment: See all_cons_columns. Just curious for what purpose do you need dynamic sql? I think you reinvent ORM.

Comment: Master Thesis - testing etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT UC.OWNER
,      UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
,      UCC1.TABLE_NAME||'.'||UCC1.COLUMN_NAME "CONSTRAINT_SOURCE"
,      'REFERENCES'
,      UCC2.TABLE_NAME||'.'||UCC2.COLUMN_NAME "REFERENCES_COLUMN"
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS uc
,    USER_CONS_COLUMNS ucc1
,    USER_CONS_COLUMNS ucc2
WHERE UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = UCC1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  AND UC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = UCC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  AND UCC1.POSITION = UCC2.POSITION -- Correction for multiple column primary keys.
  AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R'
ORDER BY UCC1.TABLE_NAME
,        UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

Comment: This will be very helpful. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Natural Join?

If the column names are consistent across two tables, the Natural Join clause will join the tables on each common column name.

For example, from the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html

> If the tables COUNTRIES and CITIES have two common columns named
>   COUNTRY and COUNTRY_ISO_CODE, the following two SELECT statements are
>   equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES NATURAL JOIN CITIES

SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES JOIN CITIES
USING (COUNTRY, COUNTRY_ISO_CODE)
```

Comment: If the `employees` and `departments` tables both have a `manager_id` column then natural join will include this in the join condition. Will the department's manager be the same as the employee's manager? Probably not, so you need to be **very** careful with natural join as it can have unintended cosequences.

Comment: Not to mention `name`, `description`, `comments`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `status` etc. And many schemas use naming conventions like `cities.country_id = countries.id` or `cities.city_ctry_id = countries.ctry_id`. I can't understand why the inventor of the Natural Join ever thought it would work.